# ruby on rails - loop through dbase records in rjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my RoR application, i have a rjs file which is populating a field with id `"submission_references"`  found in my main form.

RJS code:

```
  page[:submission_references].value = @references.each do |reference|
                                       reference.NAME
                                       end
```

The problem is that instead of displaying the retrieved database value, the following is being displayed in the `'submission_references'` field:

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

However if i put something like `@references[0].NAME`, the first retrieved record's name is displayed in the field.

Please can someone shed some light on this for me.

Many many thanks for your precious help

Comment: may you try "for reference in @references" kind of loop and let me know if its worked

Comment: :) Thank you for the suggestion, i tried: (@references.map {|reference| reference.NAME}).join(", ") and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
page[:submission_references].value = 
  (@references.map {|reference| reference.NAME}).join(", ")
```

A little explanation: in your code you have assigned to the `value` a result of `each` loop, which returns original array of objects (not the evaluated inside block). That is why you get that `[object Object],[object Object]` string. On the other side `map` iterates over a collection and it evaluates block for each object in collection. Evaluated values are then returned in array instead of orginal objects. Since `NAME` is a string, you can use `join(", ")` to join each element of an array into one string concacted with ", " string.

Comment: OMG, thank you sooo much klew :)...my code is working great now. Cheers!